# How to bind config items in an array to environment variables

Tags: go, viper-go

Here below is my configuration file in toml format.

```
[[hosts]]
name = "host1"
username = "user1"
password = "password1"

[[hosts]]
name = "host2"
username = "user2"
password = "password2"
```

... and here is my code to load it:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
    "strings"
)

type Config struct {
    Hosts []Host
}

type Host struct {
    Name      string `mapstructure:"name"`
    Username  string `mapstructure:"username"`
    Password  string `mapstructure:"password"`
}

func main() {
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    viper.AddConfigPath("./config")
    viper.SetConfigName("app")

    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error reading config file, %v", err)
    }

    config := new(Config)
    if err := viper.Unmarshal(config); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error parsing config file, %v", err)
    }

    var username, password string

    for i, h := range config.Hosts {
        if len(h.Name) == 0 {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("name not defined for host %d", i)
        }

        if username = os.Getenv(strings.ToUpper(h.Name) + "_" + "USERNAME"); len(username) > 0 {
            config.Hosts[i].Username = username
        } else if len(h.Username) == 0 {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("username not defined for %s", e.Name)
        }

        if password = os.Getenv(strings.ToUpper(e.Name) + "_" + "PASSWORD"); len(password) > 0 {
            config.Hosts[i].Password = password
        } else if len(h.Password) == 0 {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("password not defined for %s", e.Name)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Hostname: %s", h.name)
        fmt.Printf("Username: %s", h.Username)
        fmt.Printf("Password: %s", h.Password)
    }
}
```

For instance, I first check whether environment variables `HOST1_USERNAME1`, `HOST1_PASSWORD1`, `HOST2_USERNAME2`, and `HOST2_PASSWORD2` exist... if they do, then I set the configuration items to their values, otherwise I try to get the values from the configuration file.

I know viper offers method `AutomaticEnv` to do something similar... but does it work with a collection like mine (`AutomaticEnv` shall be invoked **after** environment variable binding)?

Given my code above, is it possible to use the mechanism provided by viper and remove `os.GetEnv`?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here below is my updated code. In I've defined environment variables `HOST1_USERNAME` and `HOST1_PASSWORD` and set the corresponding settings in my config file to an empty string.

Here is my new config file:

```
[host1]
username = ""
password = ""

[host2]
username = "user2"
password = "password2"
```

And here is my code:

```
package config

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

type Config struct {
    Hosts []Host
}

type Host struct {
    Name     string
    Username string
    Password string
}

var config *Config

func (c *Config) Load() (*Config, error) {
    if config == nil {
        viper.AddConfigPath(".")
        viper.AddConfigPath("./config")
        viper.SetConfigName("myapp")
        viper.AutomaticEnv()
        viper.SetEnvKeyReplacer(strings.NewReplacer(".", "_"))

        if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("error reading config file, %v", err)
        }

        allSettings := viper.AllSettings()
        hosts := make([]Host, 0, len(allSettings))

        for key, value := range allSettings {
            val := value.(map[string]interface{})

            if val["username"] == nil {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("username not defined for host %s", key)
            }

            if val["password"] == nil {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("password not defined for host %s", key)
            }

            hosts = append(hosts, Host{
                Name:      key,
                Unsername: val["username"].(string),
                Password: val["password"].(string),
            })
        }

        config = &Config{hosts}
    }

    return config, nil
}
```

I works now (thanks to Chrono Kitsune) and I hope it helps,
j3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`viper.Viper`](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/viper#Viper):

> The priority of the sources is the following:
>
> 1. overrides
> 2. flags
> 3. env. variables
> 4. config file
> 5. key/value store
> 6. defaults

You might encounter a problem in determining the name of the environment variable. You essentially need a way to bind `hosts[0].Username` to the environment variable `HOST1_USERNAME`. However, there's no way to do this in viper currently. In fact, `viper.Get("hosts[0].username")` returns `nil`, meaning array indices apparently cannot be used with `viper.BindEnv`. You also would need to use this function for as many hosts as can be defined, meaning if you have 20 hosts listed, you'd need to call `viper.BindEnv` 40 or 60 times, depending on whether the name of a host could be overridden by an environment variable. To work around this limitation, you'd need to dynamically work with hosts as independent tables rather than an array of tables:

```
[host1]
username = "user1"
password = "password1"

[host2]
username = "user2"
password = "password2"
```

You can then use [`viper.SetEnvKeyReplacer`](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/viper#SetEnvKeyReplacer) with a `strings.Replacer` to handle the environment variable issue:

```
// host1.username => HOST1_USERNAME
// host2.password => HOST2_PASSWORD
// etc.
viper.SetEnvKeyReplacer(strings.NewReplacer(".", "_"))
```

Note that at the time of this writing [some bugs exist when it comes to the resolution order](https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/309). This issue affects `viper.Unmarshal` and `viper.Get`: environment variables should override config file values, but currently the config file values are still used. Strangely, `viper.AllSettings` works fine. If it didn't, you couldn't do something like the following to work with the hosts in the above format:

```
// Manually collect hosts for storing in config.
func collectHosts() []Host {
    hosts := make([]Host, 0, 10)
    for key, value := range viper.AllSettings() {
        // viper.GetStringMapString(key)
        // won't work properly with environment vars, etc. until
        //   https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/309
        // is resolved.
        v := value.(map[string]interface{})
        hosts = append(hosts, Host{
            Name:     key,
            Username: v["username"].(string),
            Password: v["password"].(string),
        })
    }
    return hosts
}
```

To sum things up:

1. Values are supposed to be taken from the first provided of: overrides, flags, environment variables, config files, key/value stores, defaults. Unfortunately, this isn't always the order followed (because bugs).
2. You need to change your config format and use a string replacer to leverage the convenience of [`viper.AutomaticEnv`](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/viper#AutomaticEnv).

Comment: If username and passowrd for host 1 are not defined in the config file, does `AllSettings` return the value of environment variables `HOST1_USERNAME` and `HOST1_PASSWORD`? I'm asking because it seems it doesn't work - see the update in my original question.

Comment: @j3d `viper.AutomaticEnv` only works for defined keys. If they're not defined, no environment variable will be magically bound to a nonexistent key. Sadly, `viper.AllKeys()` and `viper.AllSettings()` doesn't return a `host1` key, though you can still use `viper.Get("host1")` to retrieve an empty/nil `map[string]interface{}` rather than an untyped `nil`, though it won't do you any good (what about an empty `host238471` TOML table as the only host?) If you know about a particular setting, you can set a default for it and the environment variables will work. Otherwise, you're out of luck.

Comment: OK, I've just set `HOST1_USERNAME` and `HOST1_PASSWORD` to an empty string in my config file and now it works. Many thanks Kitsune for your support :-)